# Quicksort gone wrong after first recursion?

Tags: python, quicksort

I already made some quicksort implemetation, but it creates 2 new lists for each recursion so I wanted to work on the list directly, but for some reason the changes made in the list after the first recursion dont reflect in the final list.

The code in question:

```
def quicksort(lista: list, min_lenght=3):

    def part(listb: list) -> list:
        pivot = listb[0]
        low = 0
        mid = 0
        high = len(listb) - 1
        while mid <= high:

            if listb[mid] < pivot:
                listb[low], listb[mid] = listb[mid], listb[low]
                low += 1
                mid += 1
            elif listb[mid] > pivot:
                listb[mid], listb[high] = listb[high], listb[mid]
                high -= 1
            else:
                mid += 1
        return [low, mid]

    if len(lista) <= min_lenght:
        lista.sort()
    else:
        lowmark, midmark = part(lista)

        quicksort(lista[:lowmark])
        quicksort(lista[midmark:])


lol = [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 4, 3, 25]
print(lol)
quicksort(lol)
print(lol)
```

Comment: Doing a slice like `lista[:lowmark]` or `lista[midmark:]` makes an entirely new object. Changes made to said new object won't reflect on the original list.

The only real way to do an in-place quicksort is by giving `start` and `end` indices as arguments to the function, along with the original list

Comment: Have you defined `quicksort()` function? It doesn't seem to be a built in function.

Comment: We need to be able to run and debug the code so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy YES, that was the problem, i had to restructure more of the code that i hoped to, but it now works flawlesly.